# Automatically fit images on div container while resizing window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to resize some blocks dinamically to fill a blank space caused when window resizes (I think this could be done with javascript) but how could I do this?

```js
var txt = "";
txt += "<p>innerWidth: " + window.innerWidth + " px</p>";
txt += "<p>outerWidth: " + window.outerWidth + " px</p>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  background:#fff;
  height:300px;
}

.fixed-block {
  float:left;
  height:80px;
  border:solid 2px #000;
  min-width:70px;
  background:#777;
  width:23%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-block">
  </div>
   <div class="fixed-block">
  </div>
   <div class="fixed-bblock">
  </div>
   <div class="fixed-block">
  </div>
   <div class="fixed-block">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v0hvr91/)

Comment: i have tried transform flexbox and javascript. it seems to be a need javascript code that could control dinamically the size of the container and resize blocls to query

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="fixed-block"></div>
          <div class="fixed-block"></div>
          <div class="fixed-block"></div>
          <div class="fixed-block"></div>
          <div class="fixed-block"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            window.onload = resizeDivs;
            window.onresize = resizeDivs;

            function resizeDivs() {
                var container = document.querySelector('.container');

                // Compute new size:
                var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-block');
                var divNb = divs.length;
                var divWidth = Math.round(container.clientWidth / divNb) -0.5;
                var divHeight = container.clientHeight;

                // Apply size to the divs
                for(var i=0; i<divNb; i++) {
                    var div = divs[i];
                    div.style.width = divWidth + 'px';
                    div.style.height = divHeight + 'px';
                }
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            body {
                background: lightgrey;
            }

            .container {
                width:100%;
                background:#fff;
                height:300px;
            }

            .fixed-block {
                float:left;
                height:80px;
                box-sizing: border-box;/*important as border should not be added to the size*/
                border:solid 2px #000;
                min-width:70px;
                background:#777;
                width:23%;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: a small amelioration with round calculation and execute resize at window openning

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to do this with flexbox, to get you started:

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  background:#fff;
  height:300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.fixed-block {
  height:80px;
  border:solid 2px #000;
  background:#777;
  flex: 1 0 70px;
}
```